# Local loop back message passing mechanism within a native service in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, message-queue

I have a c++ service code that runs on Linux platform which am porting to Android as a native service. That service has many sub-components which talk to each other. For this the service is using some local message passing queue. This message queue is in the form of a privately written library in Linux. I also understand that Android has Message Handler mechanism. So my doubts are:
1. Message Handler mechanism is not available in native c++ code in Android. Is this right?
2. If am porting that privately written message queue library to Android, how good it will be in using that library in Android for passing local messages within a process?

Comment: Trying to shoehorn a general-purpose messaging system into android's Looper framework sounds like a recipe for pain.

Comment: @botje thanks for the info. coming to the same conclusion after analysis